# EF core 2 migration scripts in PostgreSQL 10.5 error

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

Using EF core 2 with PostgreSQL. Normally, I add migrations and update my local PostgreSQL db with **dotnet ef database update**  without any problem. However, when we create `migrations.sql` script from our migrations and then try to execute this file using the **psql cli** we received some errors.

For example, the below script is generated by EF core 2. When I tried to run with psql, I receive:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
LINE 5: DECLARE
```

My cli command is;

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -f d:\pg\migrations.sql
```

How should I run this script? What am I missing?

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "__EFMigrationsHistory" WHERE "MigrationId" = '20181001082052_InitialCreate') THEN
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "Admin".sp_assign_role_to_user (role_name varchar, user_name varchar) RETURNS void AS $$
                    DECLARE  
                        role_id int;
                        user_id int;
                        user_role_id int;
                        role_count int;
                        user_count int;
                        user_role_count int;    
                        role_deleted_count int;
                        user_deleted_count int; 
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT INTO role_count COUNT(*) FROM "Admin"."Role" WHERE "Name"=role_name AND "IsDeleted"=0;
                        SELECT INTO user_count COUNT(*) FROM "Common"."User" WHERE "LoginName"=user_name AND "StateId"=1 AND "IsDeleted"=0; 
                        RAISE NOTICE 'role_count %',role_count;
                        RAISE NOTICE 'user_count %',user_count; 
                        SELECT INTO role_deleted_count COUNT(*) FROM "Admin"."Role" WHERE "Name"=role_name AND "IsDeleted"=1;
                        SELECT INTO user_deleted_count COUNT(*) FROM "Common"."User" WHERE "LoginName"=user_name AND ("IsDeleted"=1 OR "StateId" <> 1);     
                        IF role_count = 0 AND role_deleted_count = 0 THEN   
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'role_name: % bulunamadı!', role_name;
                            RETURN;
                        ELSIF user_count = 0 AND user_deleted_count = 0 THEN    
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'user_name: % bulunamadı!', user_name;
                            RETURN; 
                        ELSIF role_count = 0 and role_deleted_count > 0 THEN    
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'role_name: % silinmiş!',role_name;
                            RETURN; 
                        ELSIF user_count = 0 and user_deleted_count > 0 THEN    
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'user_name: % silinmiş, yada aktif durumda değil!',user_name;
                            RETURN; 
                        ELSIF role_count > 1 THEN
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'role_name: %, count: % birden fazla role!',role_name, role_count;
                            RETURN;
                        ELSIF user_count > 1 THEN   
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'user_name: % , count: % birden fazla kullanıcı adı!',user_name, user_count;
                            RETURN;
                        ELSIF role_count = 1 AND user_count = 1 THEN    
                            SELECT INTO role_id "Id" FROM "Admin"."Role" WHERE "Name"=role_name AND "IsDeleted"=0;  
                            RAISE NOTICE 'role_id: %', role_id;
                            SELECT INTO user_id "Id" FROM "Common"."User" WHERE "LoginName"=user_name AND "IsDeleted"=0 and "StateId"=1;
                            RAISE NOTICE 'user_id: %', user_id;
                        ELSE
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'tanımlanmamış durum!';
                            RETURN;
                        END IF; 
                        SELECT INTO user_role_count COUNT(*) FROM "Admin"."UserRole" WHERE "RoleId"=role_id AND "UserId"=user_id AND "IsDeleted"=0; 
                        RAISE NOTICE 'user_role_count: %', user_role_count;     
                        IF user_role_count > 0 THEN
                            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Zaten mevcut atama var!; role_name: %, role_id: % - user_name: % , user_id: %', role_name, role_id, user_name, user_id;
                            RETURN;
                        ELSE
                            INSERT INTO "Admin"."UserRole"("RoleId", "UserId","Comment", "LastUpdatedDate") VALUES(role_id, user_id, 'Created by SP_ASSIGN_ROLE_TO_USER', now());
                            RAISE NOTICE 'User Role ataması başarılı ; role_name: %, role_id: % - user_name: %', role_name, role_id, user_name;
                        END IF;     
                    END; 
                    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    END IF;
END $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dollar quoting is messed up. You use `$$` for the `DO` block as well as for the function body.

Use `$do$` to mark the beginning and end of the `DO` block and `$func$` to surround the function body. You can use different delimiters as long as you don't use the same for both.